# Building a nested JSONObject

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

Below is the code I am using

```
    JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();

    requestParams.put("something", "something value");
    requestParams.put("another.child", "child value");
```

This is how the API needs to be posted

```
{
   "something":"something value",
   "another": {
   "child": "child value"
   }
}
```

I get an error stating that "The another.child field is required."

How do I go about posting this via restAssured? The other APIs that do not require posting with nesting work, so I'm assuming that's why it's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you posted was this since `JSONObject` has no notion of dot-separated key paths.

```
{
   "something":"something value",
   "another.child": "child value"
}
```

You need to make another `JSONObject`

```
JSONObject childJSON = new JSONObject():
childJSON.put("child", "child value");
requestParams.put("another", childJSON);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a request object and then let the RestAssured library to serialise the object to json for you.

So for example:

```
        class Request {
            private String something;
            private Another another;

            public Request(final String something, final Another another) {
                this.something = something;
                this.another = another;
            }

            public String getSomething() {
                return something;
            }

            public Another getAnother() {
                return another;
            }
        }

       class Another {
            private String child;

            public Another(final String child) {
                this.child = child;
            }

            public String getChild() {
                return child;
            }
        }
```

..and then in a test method

```
@Test
public void itWorks() {
...
        Request request = new Request("something value", new Another("child value"));

        given().
                contentType("application/json").
                body(request).
        when().
                post("/message");
...
}
```

Just don't forget the line `contentType("application/json")` so that the library knows you want to use json.

See: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#serialization

Comment: I think you need a no-arg constructor for most the serialization libraries to work

Comment: For serialization from Java to json using Jackson you only need the getters (or public fields). But the other way around it's needed.