# Java Rest Assured how to update value of nested json object?

Tags: java, json, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a json like this:

```
{
    "application": "ERP",
    "subject": "Quote 0000005 from TestSG",
    "exportDocumentRequest": {
        "documentDate": "05-02-2020",
        "tenantBillingAddr": null,
        "code": "0000"
      } 
}
```

I need to replace "code" value i.e "0000" to "1234"
I tried following by refering this [Building a nested JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950819/building-a-nested-jsonobject)

```
JSONObject requestParams = Utilities.readJSON("MyFile.json");
JSONObject childJSON = new JSONObject();
childJSON.put("code", "1234");
requestParams.put("exportDocumentRequest", childJSON);
```

but it is giving me output like:

```
{
    "application": "ERP",
    "subject": "Quote 0000005 from TestSG",
    "exportDocumentRequest": {
        "code": "0000"
      } 
}
```

It is removing other child fields in "exportDocumentRequest". I need it to be like this with updated "code":

```
{
    "application": "ERP",
    "subject": "Quote 0000005 from TestSG",
    "exportDocumentRequest": {
        "documentDate": "05-02-2020",
        "tenantBillingAddr": null,
        "code": "1234"
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [How to edit, modify nested JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894559/how-to-edit-modify-nested-jsonobject)

Following worked for me.

```
requestParams.getJSONObject("exportDocumentRequest").put("code", "1234");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it with the spread operator.

A spread operator replicates values and you can explicitly update the ones you want. Like i changed `code` to `5000`

```js
let test = {
  "application": "ERP",
  "subject": "Quote 0000005 from TestSG",
  "exportDocumentRequest": {
    "documentDate": "05-02-2020",
    "tenantBillingAddr": null,
    "code": "0000"
  }
}

let updated_test = {
  ...test,
  "exportDocumentRequest": {
    ...test.exportDocumentRequest,
    "code": "5000"
  }
}

console.log(updated_test)
```

Comment: Hi, what should be the Java equivalent for this? I forgot to update this in the question. I am doing it in java rest assured library.

Comment: Follow Up here for JAVA.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894559/how-to-edit-modify-nested-jsonobject